# How do you alert on errors and warnings for an Alexa skill?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set up logging for an AWS Lambda function (node.js 8.10) that's hooked up to an Alexa skill.  I've noticed that CloudWatch can easily [alert on errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-create-alarm.html) or [route to alternate processing queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html) in the case where the lambda returns a proper error response, and you can [use metric filters to automate searching through log files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountOccurrencesExample.html) and alerting on different text.

I'm noticing two attributes of my stack that are complicating using this:

- CloudWatch doesn't seem to differentiate between node.js logging levels or stderr/stdout, which is complicating general alerting for warnings and errors.
- We usually will return well-formed Alexa responses with successful response codes even in the case of an internal failure since we want Alexa to respond with a particular response rather than a general "I ran into an error" response.

With this in mind, my questions are:

- How are other folks managing logging and alerting for nonfatal errors in your Alexa skills?
- What would be a good way of transforming my current logging into something more "alertable" in CloudWatch?
- Am I just thinking about this wrong?  Should I be handling this differently?  Or should I just be happy that I can get fatal exception alerting and not worry about alerting off of logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up adding Winston to our Lambda and using it to give our logs a parsable format.

From there, we set up a CloudWatch metric filter to look for the following pattern:

```
[logLevel="error:", ...]
```

Which then sets a flag to 1 in the case of a match.

We then set up a CloudWatch alarm to trigger an email to a SNS topic when the flag is set.  We don't get the specific log in the resulting email, but we have enough info to sign on and check logs.